# for WCF transaction, why I must close proxy before close the transactionscope?

Tags: wcf, transactions, wcf-binding, distributed-transactions

In WCF, if it's a per-call service, I can close the transactionscope before close the proxy. And for a per-session service, I must close proxy before close the transactionscope. Can you please explain the underlying mechanism why I should do this in that sequence? Thanks in advance.

Comment: "I must close proxy before close the transactionscope" - are you saying you get an error if you don't do this? Which binding are you using?